# Admob won't load ads

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I'm not getting any error or something.

I created a CustomView file, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
//CustomView.h
#import "GADBannerView.h"

@interface CustomView : UIView
{
    GADBannerView *bannerView_;

}
```

Second file:

```
//CustomView.m
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 430, 320, 50)];

bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
bannerView_.rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
NSLog(@"%@",bannerView_.rootViewController);
[self addSubview:bannerView_];


GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Additionally, is your BANNER_ID using the format "ca-ad-pub-XXXXXX../XXXX"? I saw a few changes in admob recently and some are affecting the way we use UNIT_IDs

Comment: I don't use that format, I'll try this.

Comment: try this: [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];

Comment: Jack, make that an answer and I'll be sure to upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation, you should allocate your banner like this:

```
[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
```

With the size you need, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    GADRequest.isTesting = YES;
```

should be set.

Also, are there any messages in your Xcode Console?

Comment: 2014-02-07 17:27:32.682 TaalSprint[8269:70b] <Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];

Comment: But I'm quite sure that it won't work because of the 'CustomView'.
Probably something wrong with the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

As @JackWu said, I need to use:

```
[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
```